# DataGridView write all values from a column to list

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

I'd like to write all values from column 2 to a list:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    list.Add(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString);
}
```

However, this returns an error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting, and you should be indexing column 2, in current code you are referencing first column.

Comment: Oh right, correct that now. The error is this: `'obejct' does not contain a definition for 'cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the error:

> 'obejct' does not contain a definition for 'cells' and no extension
>   method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

You need to modify your `foreach` loop and instead of `var` specify `DataGridViewRow`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow  item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    list.Add(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
```

Also you need `()` for `ToString`

If you want to use LINQ then you can do that in a single statement like:

```
List<string> list = dataGridView1.Rows
                             .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                             .Select(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                             .ToList();
```

EDIT:

The above could result in a Null Reference exception if the value of `Cell[1]` for any row is `null` you can add a check before adding which would check for existence of cell and whether it has value or not. like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (item.Cells.Count >= 2 && //atleast two columns
        item.Cells[1].Value != null) //value is not null
    {
        list.Add(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

The above check would save you from calling `ToString` on a null object and you will not get the exception.

Comment: This returns a `System.NullReferenceException` at `list.Add(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());`; using LINQ it returns the same at `r.Cells[1].Value.ToString())`

Comment: @Jacobus21, that means that you have `null` value in your column for some rows. Let me modify the answer

Comment: @Habib Can you show how to insert an empty value from the datagridview  to list?

Comment: @jacobz Does this error raise with a DGV in which you can add rows? The last row where there is an asterisk in the margin is always non-readable and should be avoided. See jk777's solution.

Answer (score 5):

To account for Null exceptions using LINQ:

```
List<string> list = dataGridView1.Rows
                       .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                       .Where(x => x.Cells[1].Value != null)
                       .Select(x => x.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting happens because `Rows` is not automatically cast to `DataGridViewRow` when you use `var`.
The correct code is:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    list.Add(row .Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
```