# How to add empty value from gridview cell to list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I want to enter guest details(Title,Firstname,midname lastname) in a `list<string>` ,the guest details can be empty.I'm using LINQ for inserting in the list.I had referred this question for the LINQ code [DataGridView write all values from a column to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314109/datagridview-write-all-values-from-a-column-to-list)

All I want to do is enter the text into the list if it has or insert empty string if it doesn't have.Right now if I leave textboxes blank it will throw `object reference not set to instance of an object exception`

```
private string SaveGuestDetails()
        {
            string strRet = string.Empty;
            Reservation obj = new Reservation();
            FinalReservationDetails f = new FinalReservationDetails();

            try
            {
                //int i = dgvTextBoxes.Rows.Count;
                List<DataRow> personsList = new List<DataRow>();
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvTextBoxes.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    f.SubSrNo = j + 1;

                      f.GuestTitle = dgvTextBoxes.Rows
                   .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .Select(r => r.Cells["txtTitle"].Value.ToString())
                   .ToList();

                f.FirstName = dgvTextBoxes.Rows
                    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Select(r => r.Cells["txtFname"].Value.ToString())
                    .ToList();

                f.MidName = dgvTextBoxes.Rows
                    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Select(r => r.Cells["txtMName"].Value.ToString())
                    .ToList();

                f.LastName = dgvTextBoxes.Rows
                    .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Select(r => r.Cells["txtLname"].Value.ToString())
                    .ToList();

                 }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return strRet;
        }
```

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht No man .I want to insert empty cell if its present

Comment: I stick with [What is a NullReferenceException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). You have it somewhere in your code and you ask others to find it. If you have a specific question, ask more specific. For example, post your stacktrace and tell, which object is `null`. Then think about why it is so and when you have no clue, ask again.

Comment: yep find out what is null. And you can remove the `for loop` your LINQ selects the whole column and stores the list in your object `f` so each iteration is doing the same.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht my question is not about null reference ,but want to insert empty textboxes in the list

Comment: you have to handle cases of Cell.Value is null or DbNull. Best way is to use the **null-coalescing operator**. `f.GuestTitle = dgvTextBoxes.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => (r.Cells["txtTitle"].Value as string) ?? string.Empty ).ToList();`

Comment: @Koryu that solved my problem thanks but my question didn't need to be downvoted

Comment: havent downvoted it :)  see my answer for detailed information how to convert to string in this case.

Comment: @Koryu the comment was itself helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your cell values can be string, DBNull.Value or null.
`null.ToString()` throws the `object reference not set to instance of an object exception`. To avoid that you can first set your object `as string` to get rid of the DBNull.Value and then use the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to set null to empty string.

```
object unknown = System.DBNull.Value;
string converted1 = (unknown as string) ?? string.Empty;
// returns string.Empty

unknown = null;
string converted2 = (unknown as string) ?? string.Empty;
// returns string.Empty

unknown = "text";
string converted3 = (unknown as string) ?? string.Empty;
// returns text
```

In your case:

```
f.GuestTitle = dgvTextBoxes.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Select
(r => (r.Cells["txtTitle"].Value as string) ?? string.Empty ).ToList();
```