# datagridview column sum in textbox

Tags: c#

I want `datagridview` column sum in `TextBox`

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(SNoTextBox.Text, PriceTextBox.Text, QtyTextBox.Text);

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qty"].Index].Value));
    }
}
```

I'm using above code to insert data in `datagridview` and I want the sum of `AMOUNT` column in `GrandTotalTextBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Try this:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal amount =0;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(SNoTextBox.Text, PriceTextBox.Text, QtyTextBox.Text);

     foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
           row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qty"].Index].Value));

           amount += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value);
      }
    GrandTotalTextBox.Text = amount.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There would also be a `Linq` Solution to this:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(SNoTextBox.Text, PriceTextBox.Text, QtyTextBox.Text);

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qty"].Index].Value));
    }
}

List<decimal> list = dataGridView1.Rows
         .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
         .Select(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString()))
         .ToList();

GrandTotalTextBox.Text = list.Sum().ToString();
```

with friendly help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314109/datagridview-write-all-values-from-a-column-to-list)