# Why does matching a value of a column in a datagridview row by row consume a lot of memory?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridview` object called `dgv` whereby its `DataSource` property is set to a `BindingSource` object which in turn points to a `DataTable` object called `ds.DataTable1`. `DataTable1` has a `Name` column.

Firstly, I had it load 700,000 fully-filled rows by using `tableAdapter.Fill(ds.dataTable1)`. Then I run a search using a for-loop like so:

```
int rowCount = dgv.Rows.Count;
string searchName = "zelda";
// Search next record
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[column1.Name].Value.ToString() == searchName.ToUpper())
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I realized that this search uses more than the amount of memory used to `Fill` in the dataset. To illustrate, when I initialize the app, it consumes just around 50 MB. When I `Fill` the dataset, memory consumption reaches 600 MB. When I run the search, the memory usage reached 1.5 GB before it encounters the out-of-memory error as my app is a 32-bit one.

I have found out that this line

```
if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[column1.Name].Value.ToString() == searchName.ToUpper())
```

is the culprit.

Any idea why calling this line for hundreds of thousands of time consume such a large amount of memory? I understand that this datagridview consumes lots of memory as it needs to hold large amount of data but do not really understand why the process of looping and searching for a match in every row in the DataGridview causes even larger memory consumption.

I am fairly new to memory management so would appreciate some references to resources that explain this.

Comment: I think you want to search your bound datatable in your adapter instead of your datagridview. You can use the [datatable search method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netcore-3.1) to return an array of datatable rows.

Comment: Or if your just filtering datagridview rows by a search, use the [rowfilter on the bound table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049875/3585500)

Comment: I am confident that presenting the user with 700,000 rows of data is not going to be useful. Assuming the data is in a data base, then I cannot imagine that the “search” query to the data base would take longer or consume more memory that ANY looping through the grid or data table as you are attempting. Can you explain “why” so much data needs to be presented to the user and how is the data originally stored? I would think with that much data, the user would type what they are searching for, THEN query the data base for just that. I am guessing I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

For each row, you're calling the full row in the entire datagridview, while you only need one column for it.

You can shorten up the call by making a list that contains only the column you're searching for. Perhaps it'll cost less memory to make the dgv into one column, and then check for it's values afterwards.

this query can help you to recieve only the column values:

```
List<string> columnvalues = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    columnvalues.Add(row.Cells[column1.Name].Value.ToString());
}

if (columnvalues.Contains(searchName.ToUpper())
{
    break;
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314241/2735344